# Barplot columns uneven despite being equal in value

Tags: r, plot

I've got a matrix that I've plotted using the bar plot function to create a stacked bar plot of changes in percent of something (alphabets) over time.  The matrix looks like:

```
Year    V   W   X   Y   Z
1   7.5397  20.6349 11.1111 0.3968  60.3175
2   8.3333  21.4286 11.9048 0.3968  57.9365
3   23.8095 9.5238  9.5238  0.3968  56.7460
4   23.4127 10.7143 10.3175 1.1905  54.3651
5   23.4127 11.1111 10.7143 1.9841  52.7778
6   30.0000 2.4000  19.2000 2.4000  46.0000
```

All these should be the same height, because they add to 100, but in my plot, all the heights are just a bit different at the top.  My bar plot code looks like this:

```
>barplot(t(as.matrix(mydata[,2:6])),names.arg=unique(mydata$Year),axis.lty=1, ylim=c(0,100), 
    xlab="Year", ylab="Percent of Categories", etc.
```

I've tried adjusting the ylim, changing xpd to =FALSE, and making some axis argument adjustments, and I'm not sure what else to try before scratching the whole thing and retrying with a different plotting function.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: They look the same to me. Am I missing something? http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ijhr.png

Comment: The plot also looks fine to me. Can you show us what additional code is in the `etc.`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for offering help, I just figured out what my problem was..... me!